# Cholesky Decomposition for positive semidefinite separation

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Cholesky decomposition is a common way to test positive semi definiteness of a symmetric matrix $A$. If the algorithm "goes wrong" trying to take a square root of a negative number, I know the matrix isn't PD.

How can I use this algorithm (any of the ways to represent it) to find a vector $x$ such that $x^TAx < 0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that the symmetric $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ can be partitioned as
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{A} & a \\ a^T & \alpha
\end{bmatrix}, \quad \tilde{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{(n-1)\times(n-1)}
$$ 
and that $\tilde{A}$ is SPD. When looking for the Cholesky factor $L$ of $A$ in the conformingly partitioned form
$$
L=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{L} & 0 \\ l^T & \lambda\end{bmatrix},
$$
the algorithm won't fail during the first $n-1$ steps and gives you the Cholesky factorisation of the $\tilde{A}$ block ($\tilde{A}=\tilde{L}\tilde{L}^T$) together with the vector $l=\tilde{L}^{-1}a$ but fails to compute the diagonal element $\lambda$ because $\alpha-l^Tl=\alpha-a^TA^{-1}a<0$. However, you can obtain the following factorisation:
$$
A=\hat{L}D\hat{L}^T,
$$
where 
$$
\hat{L}=\begin{bmatrix}\tilde{L}&0\\l^T&1\end{bmatrix},
\quad D=\begin{bmatrix}I_{n-1}&0\\0&\delta\end{bmatrix},
\quad \delta=\alpha-l^Tl<0
$$
($I_{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ identity matrix).
With this factorisation at hand (and $e_n=[0,\ldots,0,1]^T$ being the last column of $I_n$), you have
$$
\delta=e_n^TDe_n=e_n^T\hat{L}^{-1}\hat{L}D\hat{L}^T\hat{L}^{-T}e_n=e_n^T\hat{L}^{-1}A\hat{L}^{-T}e_n=x^TAx<0,
$$
where $x=\hat{L}^{-T}e_n$ is the last column of $\hat{L}^{-T}$ (or the transpose of the last row of $\hat{L}^{-1}$). Note that (since we can easily express $\hat{L}^{-1}$ using the partitioning of $\hat{L}$) this vector is given by
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}
-\tilde{L}^{-T}l\\1
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\tilde{A}^{-1}a\\1
\end{bmatrix},
$$
so its computation requires only a backward solve with $\tilde{L}^T$.

In the general case, when the Cholesky factorisation fails "in the middle" of the matrix, assume that partitioning of $A$ in the form
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{12}^T & A_{22}\end{bmatrix},
$$
such that the Cholesky factorisation fails in the last step of the factorisation of $A_{11}$. Using the same approach as above, you can find $x$ such that $x^TA_{11}x<0$ and hence with $y=[x^T,0]^T$, $y^TAy=x^TA_{11}x<0$.

Comment: There is no need for $A$ to be written in the way of @Algebraic Pavel done in the general case. For the general case, in the case that the algorithm finds a negative $\delta$, you can use the fact that every submatrix of $A$ is positive-definite to develop the same argument in the first paragraph for a appropriate submatrix. Since the algorithm finds the $L$ matrix by lines, this argument works.

Answer (score 1):

Why Cholesky ? Use the Gauss method (decomposition in squares) to obtain an invertible matrix $P$ s.t. $P^TAP=diag(a_i)$ where $a_i=0,1$ or $-1$. If $a_k=-1$, then take $x=P_k$, the column with index $k$ of $P$.

EDIT: Pavel, Fabricio, you are wrong for $4$ reasons.

a) The method $LDL^T$ is a reasoning by recurrence (at each step a variable is removed)  and we can stop the process when you obtain a negative coefficient: $x^TAx=u_1{f_1}^2+\cdots+u_k{f_{i-1}}^2-v{f_i}^2+\phi(x_{i+1},\cdots,x_n)$ where $u_i>0,v>0$. You obtain a solution $x$, solving $\{f_1(x)=\cdots=f_{i-1}(x)=0,f_i(x)=1,x_{i+1}=\dots=x_n=0\}$.

b) The previous method works even if $A$ is non-invertible. On the contrary, using the Cholesky method, if you obtain a zero coefficient before obtaining a negative coefficient, then you are dead !

c) The complexities of Cholesky method and $LDL^T$ method are similar. cf.     http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4144

d) Using $LDL^T$ method, you do not need to extract square roots.

Comment: ...because the Gauss method requires to compute the full $LDL^T$ factorisation while using a failed Cholesky can be much cheaper.

Comment: I was simply answering the question, how the Cholesky factorisation can be used to achieve the defined goal (for a nonsingular $A$). One can of course use the partial $LDL^T$ factorisation. By the way, there's also an issue with zero pivots even in the nonsingular case, as the famous example of $\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ illustrates when $2\times 2$ pivots are required.

Comment: Thank you @loup, I understand what you've said. In fact, your method is more useful when dealing with nonsingular matrices and can be stopped in the middle, like Cholesky. (and for the application of my interest - identify sdp or find x st $x^TAx < 0$ - I don't need to take square roots, but I won`t get the diagonal matrix with 1,0,-1)

@Algebraic, this case with zero pivots identify a not sdp matrix and the vector x will be $x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ or $x = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}$ if the matrix is like $\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: OK, Pavel, Fabricio.